# How to control to do events or not in OnResume()?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, onresume

```
 protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        //if the page comes from another Activity, don't need to do ShowCurrentPage() to refresh page 
        //if I press the home button, then the page comes from home page , need to  do ShowCurrentPage() to refresh page 
        ShowCurrentPage();
    }
```

what my question is, how to distinguish the origin from home page or Activity when I do the OnResume() to show Activity ?

And if I need to do different event in OnResume() according to different origin of Activity, if I must write if{} before ShowCurrentPage()

Wating for good answers, Thank you!

Comment: use preference in ur case and track the record from which activity you are coming from !

Comment: try @Radhey comment like that, if you are in any other activity means set the preference value at false, if you want to call the ShowCurrentPage() method set the preference value at true in Home screen button click,based on the the value you call the method.

Comment: yup, you can manage application flow multiple ways .BUT this is the easiest way in your case as you are using activities in your app. thanks for the suggestion @Ram :) and developer are smart enough what another one trying to say ,they catch immediately ,if not then and then we should explain what is the exact flow.

Comment: Thank you for quick replies @Ram Radhey  I got it! Does that mean I also can use Plugin.Settings to save the record and then track? Because I'm also do same wok for iOS

Comment: Thank you for quick replies @Radhey Ram I got it! Does that mean I also can use Plugin.Settings to save the record and then track? Because I'm also do same wok for iOS

Comment: equivalent to shared preferences in ios , you can use NSUserDefaults to store value locally until your application not being uninstall.

Comment: Now I totally got it! Thank you for help @Radhey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Forms : Use Plugin.Settings to store value as local data in your device, base on this value to do ShowCurrentPage() method or not. As when page comes from home page, set value in OnStop()

Native apps : Use sharedpreferences...